# Find latest modified *.c file and compile it within terminal with pipelining?

Tags: command-line, compiling, c, pipe, compiler

Lately I have coded a little bit more with the terminal in Linux to get a deeper understanding of programming. Right now I am trying to automatize the compiling process with the following command:

```
find . -type f -mmin -1 -name "*.c" | gcc -o output.o -xc -
```

It basicly should find the latest modified file with ending `"*.c"` and compile it. However I always get the following error:

```
<stdin>:1:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘.’ token
```

Could anybody help me and explain what I am doing wrong or show me an alternative?

Thank you very much and have a nice day!

Comment: "I am trying to automatize the compiling process" – You should strongly consider using "make" with a Makefile, or any other similar tool whose job is to manage compilations, rather than coming up with individual hacks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are piping the *name* of the file as code to be compiled by `gcc`

You can pass the name as a file argument instead using `xargs`:

```
find . -type f -mmin -1 -name "*.c" | xargs gcc -o output.o -xc
```

However the "right" tool for this job is really `make` - which will determine what targets are older than their prerequisites and compile them as required.